# Postman `Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop` after configuring Kubernetes and Ingress Nginx with SSL Certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, postman

I'm getting the following error on Postman after creating my own self-signed SSL certificate and making the necessary configurations in Kubernetes and Ingress Nginx:

```
Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop https:\\...
```

Chrome seems to work fine and the connection is secure, but Postman returns this error when making any type of request.

The steps I followed for making my connection secure are the following:

1. Created a self-signed certificate
2. Created a ca-cert issuer from Kubernetes cert-manager
3. Configured ingress by adding the following lines inside the ingress config file:

   ```
   -   tls:
        - hosts:
            - example.dev
          secretName: dev-sc-secret

    cert-manager.io/issuer: ca-cert-issuer
   ```

I've set the settings of the certificate to trusted, and added the certificate to Postman.

Anybody has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @user3754251, could you add  to the question your postman request?